# PHP preg_match regex for matching a previous group in the pattern?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I saw this question in Stackoverflow but the answers didn't help.
Actually i need to reference to previous group in my regex pattern.

```
  $s = "1:1";

  $p = "/([0-9]):\1/";
  echo preg_match($p, $s); // False
```

OR

```
  $p = "/([0-9]):$1/";
  echo preg_match($p, $s); // False
```

Comment: use single quotes, otherwise `\1` in double quotes is interpreted  as the octal representation of a character.

Comment: $1 is for getting thematched values so it should be used in replace string

Comment: for example p = /(1a)(2a)/ now you replacement is /$1 -- $2/ to output like this 1a -- 2a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape backslash

```
<?php
  $s = "1:1";
  $p = "/([0-9]):\\1/";
  echo preg_match($p, $s);
  // Output: 1
```

(all is written in comments, but anyway)

Strings in double quotes are interpreted by php. In this case \1 turns into octal 1. To make slash you need escaped it by itself `\\`.

Or you can use uninterpreted string in single quotes `'/([0-9]):\1/'`

Comment: *Escape backslash* **Why?**

Comment: backslash is not needed

Comment: si mple, `$p = '/([0-9]):\1/';`

Answer (score 1):

use directly   `$p = "/([0-9]):?1/";`